# How to find matrix $C$ satisfying $AB=CA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where $A$ is singular, how to solve the following matrix in $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

$$AB=CA$$

Answer (score 2):

There might not be such a matrix.  Note that if $AB = CA$, $\ker(A) \subseteq \ker(AB)$.
That turns out to be a necessary and sufficient condition.
That is, if $\ker(A) \subseteq \ker(AB)$,  you can take $C = A B A^+$ where  $A^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$.  Then $CA = AB A^+ A$, and since $A^+ A$ is the orthogonal projection on the orthogonal complement of $\ker(A)$, you have
$CA x = A B x$ for any $x$ in that orthogonal complement, while by assumption
$CA x = A B x = 0$ for $x \in \ker(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an answer without the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, this is really just a system of equations.  To see this, do the following:

1. Write the matrix $C$ as a matrix of variables (replace each entry of $C$ with a variable such as $c_{ij}$).
2. Multiply out the left-hand-side, you'll get a matrix of numbers.
3. Multiply out the right-hand-side, you'll get a matrix full of linear forms.
4. Then, set each right-hand-side linear form equal to the corresponding number on the left-hand-side.
5. Now, solve this system of equations, if it's consistent, any solution will give a desired $C$.

Comment: I guess the respective system of equations can be written as $(I_n\otimes A^\top) \cdot\mathrm{vect}\, C^\top=\mathrm{vect}\, (AB)^\top$

Comment: @Dmitry That looks right to me (but I didn't check that everything was in the right place).