# Existence of matrix $C$ such that $AB = CA$ for rectangular $A$ and invertible $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

My question is similar to [How to find matrix $C$ satisfying $AB=CA$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782395/how-to-find-matrix-c-satisfying-ab-ca) but the matrix $A$ is rectangular. That is, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $m>n$ and $A$ has full column rank, and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is invertible.

Is there a matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ such that $AB = CA$?

I wonder if the statement '$AB = CA$ if and only if $ker(A) \subseteq ker(AB)$' (from [How to find matrix $C$ satisfying $AB=CA$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782395/how-to-find-matrix-c-satisfying-ab-ca)) is true for the case of rectangular, full column rank $A$.

I can see that $ker(A) \subseteq ker(AB)$ is necessary for the existence of $C$, but I'm not sure if it is a sufficient condition for the existence of $C$.

Edit: since $A$ has full column rank (i.e. linearly independent columns), we have $A^+ = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, and let $C = ABA^+$, then $CA = (AB(A^TA)^{-1}A^T)A = AB$.

Comment: Another approach: If $A$ has full column rank, then $$\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^T)=n$$ This means the columns of $A^T$ span all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so $A^TX=B^TA^T$ can be solved for $X$. Now take $C=X^T$.

Comment: @MatthewH. Thanks! Did not think of solving multiple linear systems.